# onclick the specific div's id will be clicked replace the title the of the div with the title of the uploaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 divs with classname "upload". Each upload class is used for input file.i have to hide the the input file button and use my customized button.but now onclick browsing 6 file uploads.how to get the file upload option only for the clicked div???? And how to change the title of the clicked div with the title of the file i selected for upload.

```
        <div class="col-md-4 atm">
        <div class="photo" style="background: none">
            <?php echo $this->Html->image('/students_tmp_design/images/file-upload.png', array('alt' => '', 'id' => 'photoStyle'));?>
        </div><!--End of photo-->
        <div class="upload" id="yourBtn">UPLOAD FORWARDING LETTER</div>
                <div class="hiddenBtn">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->file('letter', array('id' => 'upfile', 'onchange'=>'sub(this)')); ?>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 atm">
        <div class="photo" style="background: none">
            <?php echo $this->Html->image('/students_tmp_design/images/file-upload.png', array('alt' => '', 'id' => 'photoStyle',));?>
        </div><!--End of photo-->
        <div class="upload" id="yourBtn">UPLOAD NEWSPAPER CIRCULAR</div>
                <div class="hiddenBtn">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->file('news', array('id' => 'upfile', 'onchange'=>'sub(this)')); ?>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 atm">
        <div class="photo" style="background: none">
            <?php echo $this->Html->image('/students_tmp_design/images/file-upload.png', array('alt' => '', 'id' => 'photoStyle'));?>
        </div><!--End of photo-->
        <div class="upload" id="yourBtn">UPLOAD SMC APPROVAL LETTER</div>
                <div class="hiddenBtn">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->file('smc_letter', array('id' => 'upfile', 'onchange'=>'sub(this)')); ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

$('.upload').on('click',function(){
    $('#upfile').click();
    });
function sub(obj){
    var file = obj.value;
    var fileName = file.split("\\");
    document.getElementById("yourBtn").innerHTML = fileName[fileName.length-1];
    document.myForm.submit();
    event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: use specific id for each div....

Comment: Rishab's answer will work, but you should really avoid using the same ID on multiple elements on the same page. There's really no reason to even use the same ID in this case - just give each of your upload divs a seperate ID, and each of your 'upfile' elements as well.

Comment: sorry its not solved...clicking all the 3 uploads

Comment: I have edited my answer. Let me know if it worked

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible, set an `id` for each `div`. Then in your event listener you can refer to the `event.target` to check which `div` element was clicked.

For example:

```
    $('.upload').on('click', function (event) {
      var divID = event.target.id;
      // some logic with ifs or a switch
      // ...
      $('#upfile').click();
    });
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, I will give a more comprehensive answer. I am not super strong in PHP, but this is how I would set this up:

PHP Code defines DOM elements

```
    <?php
      $uploadDIVs = [
        "letter" => "FORWARDING LETTER",
        "news" => "NEWSPAPER CIRCULAR",
        "sms_letter" => "SMC APPROVAL LETTER"
      ];

      foreach($uploadDIVs as $key=>$value): ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 atm">
          <div class="photo" style="background: none">
            <?php echo $this->Html->image('/students_tmp_design/images/file-upload.png', array('alt' => '', 'id' => 'photoStyle'));?>
          </div><!--End of photo-->

          <div class="upload" id=""button-".$key>UPLOAD <?php echo $value ?></div>
            <div class="hiddenBtn">
              <?php echo $this->Form->file($key, array('id' => "upfile-".$key, 'onchange'=>'sub(this)')); ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

JS (jquery?) code controlling the button action

```
    $('.upload').on('click',function(event){
      // get the clicked DIV's id
      var divClickedID = event.target.id;
      // execute the 'click()' function on the proper button
      $('#upfile-' + extractID(divClickedID)).click();
    });

    function sub(obj){
      var file = obj.value;
      var fileName = file.split("\\");
      document.getElementById("button-" + extractID(obj.id)).innerHTML = fileName[fileName.length-1];
      document.myForm.submit();
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    function extractID (elementID) {
      return elementID.substr(elementID.indexOf("-" + 1);
    }
```

Comment: but now after upload i need to change the title of the upload button and give it the name of the uploaded file.how can i do it??

Comment: This is a separate question. If you need to change the text of the `button` element you can use `innerHTML`, i.e.: `button.innerHTML = “new text”`.

Comment: sorry this function doesnt work...on click it is uploading in all the divs.

Comment: You should use a unique `id` for the button that is somehow tied to the `id` of the div, i.e.: `upfile-div1`. That way when the `div` is clicked you can use the `event.target.id` to click a specific button.

Comment: in that way i have to write that jqurey code for 3 times for 3 divs respectively...that will be pretty hard...coz i have about 10 divs of uplaods..

Answer (score 0):

Hi Solution for your question:
This will trigger only particular div #upfile element

```
$('.upload').on('click',function(){
  $(this).find('#upfile').click();// 
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you please update your code so we could know current scenario

Comment: Please provide the front-end code, excluding php one

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196765/on-click-event Let continue further query in chat